# How to calculate the date of a Blog post in hours days months and years?

Tags: django

I have a Blog Post and would like to calculate the day, months and years elapsed?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like it in a format like 1 year ago, 2 days ago, 2 hrs ago.

Comment: In a template you can use `naturaltime` from django.contrib.humanize https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

Comment: Invalid filter: 'naturalday' or naturaltime. Both dont work

Comment: You have to add `{% load humanize %}` to the top of your template to load the humanize tags and add `django.contrib.humanize` to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. The linked doc has the details at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

`Posted {{post.created_on|timesince}} ago.`

See [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

I think this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey @sly_Chandan, if this solves this problem, kindly accept it :)